# How to get my current branch name from where I am pushing the code to remote server in a pre-receive hook?

Tags: bitbucket

I am trying to get the current branch name from where I am pushing the code to the branch in the remote server .

Example: My local branch name is `s095_Development` and I am pushing the code from my local to master .

I want to get the local branch name in my pre-receive hook.

```
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')
current_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | cut -d'_' -f1 | cut -d'/' -f3 )
current_branch=$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD | cut -d'_' -f1 | cut -d'/' -f3 )
```

I have used all the above but nothing seems to work for me - I am not able to get the current branch name.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command in the directory where your project is.

```
git branch
```

When using `git push`, it pushes to that branch but in the remote server. Thus, if you are currently in `master`, you'll be pushing to `remotes/origin/master`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me using PHP executing a pre-receive hook on server

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$stdin      = trim(fgets(STDIN));
$branchName = end(explode('/', end(explode(' ', $stdin))));
```